# My GRUB is stuck

Tags: uninstall

I recently installed zorin os, and I wanted to uninstall it. I followed the instructions and I booted into live os, deleted the ext4 and linux-swap partitions, and rebooted. I always get the error

```
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode…
grub rescue>
```

I burned multiple Windows XP recovery disks, only one of which booted. It was the one I made with Acer eRecovery a long time ago. I set BIOS to boot from USBCDROM (usb dvd/cd drive). I was wondering how to completely remove grub from my hard drive or fix my xp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set ZorinOS up on Dual Boot with Windows? However, get a ZorinOS live CD and open Terminal there.
Now enter these commands:

```
sudo update-grub

sudo reboot
```

That's all.